# Flask app on EC2 failing health checks while process is still running

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2, health-check

I have a flask app deployed on EC2 instances (8 workers per instance) that are part of an auto-scaling group. 95% of the time, the workers handle API calls that take <5 second. Once a day though, there is a 2+ hour ETL operation that will run on one of the workers. Edit - additional details: the flask app works with a celery backend/broker which is connected to a Redis cache on AWS.

The problem I'm running into is that when the EC2 instance fails a health check (AWS EC2 type health check), then the instance is terminated while the long ETL process is still running. I've done my best to diagnose the error and as far as I can tell, the ETL process isn't causing the health check to fail. I'm basing this on the fact that the ETL process generally completes fine on the weekends when API calls are much more rare. There is also nothing in the logs that indicates to me the instance are having issues handling long API calls - usually there are numerous successful API returns just prior to the health check failure.

I am stuck trying to figure out what to diagnose / how to prevent the long ETL process from being terminated. Some ideas I've had:

1. The health check might be failing because the queue is busy - should I reserve a queue/worker just for health check purposes?
2. Can I use a lifecycle hook to gracefully wait until the ETL process is completed? The documentation suggests that an instance marked as unhealthy may be terminated even with a hook
3. Can I setup an alternative health check where each API call success publishes a message or updates a status? The current health check is an API call to a specific endpoint

Any suggestions or feedback is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: "The health check might be failing because the queue is busy - should I reserve a queue/worker just for health check purposes?" This is the only mention of a queue anywhere in your question. It would be helpful if you described in detail what queue you are talking about here.